# Insert in Binding elements of an ObservableCollection of a class

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a `HumorDiary` class, which contains an `ObservableCollection <IconDiary> IconDiaries` property inside. In the XAML code I have a `CollectionView` and in the `ItemsSource` property I would like to insert the `IconDiaries` property in Binding, I tried like this but it doesn't work

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference pageMain}, Path=x:Static  local:HumorDiary.IconDiaries}"
```

Comment: No, it is not a static class

Comment: if the BindingContext of the page is `HumorDiary` then `ItemsSource="{Binding IconDiaries}" should work.  If not, then what is the BindingContext of the page?

Comment: @Cfun Exception: Can not find the object referenced by HumorDiary. PageMain is the x: Name of the ContentPage. I haven't declared the binding context on the page.

Comment: It simply works with the method of @Jason :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the `BindingContext` of the page is an instance of `HumorDiary` then

```
ItemsSource="{Binding IconDiaries}"
```

should work.